# Simulating lotto with R

Tags: r, for-loop, simulation

What is the simplest way to make a lotto simulator. Lets assume that I bought 10 different combinations ( 7 out of 39). So how to calculate the expected value of  winning if for 4,5,6,7 correct numbers I get 5$,70$,6500$ and 350000$. And how to simulate  the probability (and plot) to win something in for example from 1 to 10000 drawings with my 10 different combinations.

```
    set.seed(99)
    tickets<-10
    y<-replicate(tickets,sample(1:39,7,replace=FALSE))
    dimnames(y)<-list(rownames(y,do.NULL=FALSE,prefix=""),
              colnames(y,do.NULL=FALSE,prefix="combination"))
    m<-t(y)
   (m2=t(apply(m,1,sort))) 

                    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
    combinations1     5   19   23   26   33   36   39
    combinations2     7   12   14   18   20   22   37
    combinations3     4    7    8   14   25   27   36
    combinations4     1    4   13   22   27   28   32
    combinations5     1    2    8   12   13   19   37
    combinations6    16   18   22   27   30   31   35
    combinations7    13   15   18   20   31   34   36
    combinations8     5   10   27   28   29   31   35
    combinations9     4   10   14   21   23   33   35
    combinations10    1   17   20   28   29   32   33
```

Comment: I don't know anything about lotto, can you specify what a winning combination looks like? Is it consecutive numbers, or can they be any number in the combination?

Comment: It can be any number in combination (7 numbers out of 39) with 4 or more matching numbers from my 10 combinations

Comment: It's kind of bad form to post the same question to both [cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120890/lotto-simulation-with-r) and here at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not the whole answer... but the compare part

```
winningNumbers=sample(1:39,7,replace=FALSE)
numberOfNumbersRight=apply(m2,1,function(x)sum(x%in%winningNumbers))
```

then you just loop over them...

```
for(i in numberOfNumbersRight){
  if(i>5)print("you won a cheap prize")
}
```

Comment: This is basically correct but I need to simulate 1 to 1000 drawings with a loop and plot the winnings or probabilities for every drawing.

Comment: Ok is working but still how to plot the probabilities and the winnings from 1 to 10000 drawings, so that i see that the probability of winning increases with the numbers of drawings

Comment: So the basic idea is too see how probabilities increase with the drawings.I simulate the drawings and then I plot 4 lines ( for having 4,5,6,7 correct numbers) to see how probabilities increase.

Comment: a you should count the number of winnings per iteration, and then plot iteration number (x), vs total number of winnings (y)

Comment: But how to count the number of winnings per iteration?